# Why JavaScript converts my < into &gt;

Tags: javascript

JavaScript converts my `<` into `&gt;`. I want to alert it but my message is with encoded marks like `@#&amp;*()}{&gt;?&gt;?` - how to **display it normally** but **prevent from executing** as HTML code?

```
<span id="ID" onClick="alertIt(this.id);">

    <p>Some string with special chars: ~!@#&*()}{>?>?>|{">@#$#^#$</p>

    <p>Why when clicked it gives something like this:</p>

    <p>'<br>
    Some string with special chars: ~!@#&amp;*()}{&gt;?&gt;?>|... and so on
    <br>'</p>

</span>

<script type="text/javascript">

function alertIt(ID)
{

    var ID = ID;
    var content = document.getElementById(ID).innerHTML;

    alert(content);

}

</script>
```

Comment: Your original content isn't valid HTML.

Comment: @Wooble it's not an asnwer for my question

Comment: That's why I posted it as a comment and not an answer. But the upshot is that JS can't treat it as HTML without first applying some method of converting it to HTML. For historical reasons, the browser doesn't just refuse to display the page at all and throw up a big error message telling the user they've navigated to a broken page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `innerText` instead of `innerHTML`. http://jsfiddle.net/WVf95/

Comment: Its `undefined` now (for Firefox)

Comment: Yea, you might need to normalize across browsers. Something like `innerText || textContent`. See http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you use the wrong approach to get the text to display with `alert()`.

Some characters are illegal in HTML text (they are used for HTML tags and entities). `innerHTML` will make sure that text is properly escaped (i.e. you can see tags and escaped text).

If you want to see tag and text in `alert()`, there is no solution.

If you want only the text, then you will have to extract it yourself. There is no built-in support for that. It's also not really trivial to implement. I suggest to include [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) in your page; then you can get the text with:

```
function alertIt(ID) {
    alert($(ID).text());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `textContent` instaed of `innerHTML` or `innerText` is a solution.